# How to retrieve viewmodel data from one controller out of an ajax call

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an ajax call that calls a method in a controller where I assign data to a viewmodel that I want to be able to read out on the view. I am having trouble passing the updated viewmodel to the view after the controller method is complete.

**Javascript**

```
$ANALYZE = $('#submitID');

$ANALYZE.click(function () {
    var objectID = document.getElementById('objectIDInput').value;

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("AnalyzeData")',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { 'objectID': objectID },
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response.responseText);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(response.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index(AnalyzeViewModel data)
{
    //Display table to view
    AnalyzeViewModel avm = new AnalyzeViewModel();
    if (data != null)
        avm.fileData = data.fileData;
    else
        avm.fileData = null;

    return View(avm);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AnalyzeData (int objectID)
{
    List<string> retList = new List<string>();
    AnalyzeViewModel avm = new AnalyzeViewModel();

    try {
        retList = SOME LIST

        avm.fileData = retList.ToArray();

        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
        var obj = new
        {
            success = true,
            responseText = "Zones data has been calculated."
        };
        return Json(obj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**View**

```
<tbody class="scrollContent">
    @if (Model.fileData != null)
    {
        foreach (string line in Model.fileData)
        {
            @Html.Raw(line);
        }
    }
</tbody>
```

Comment: Your making an ajax call. Ajax calls do not redirect so your `return RedirectToAction()` makes no sense. And you have specified `dataType: "json",` but you returning html so that would be throwing an error. And what your returning does not contain a property named `responseText`

Comment: Please re-look at the code, I mistyped my code. should make a little more sense, and it still doesn't work to update the view model. Also would like more of an answer rather than a critique.

Comment: Are you receiving an error? What seems to be the issue?

Comment: So what is the problem? (and as a side note you do not need `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` - its a POST)

Comment: And why are you initializing a `AnalyzeViewModel ` model and populating it but then never returning it back to the client?

Comment: I am not getting an error, I am trying to return the view model with the updated data but it isn't returning to the client. I get the successful response but my table in the view never gets populated with the new data in the viewmodel

Comment: Your not returning the model in the method, just a `JsonResult` containing 2 properties.

Comment: As Stephen said, you're only returning `obj` with properties of `success` and `responseText`. Perhaps you're meaning to also return the `avm` variable?

Comment: I think I know what you guys are saying and I think i fixed it. on my return statement it reads "return Json(avm.fileData);" and now I get the code back into the view.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can write a code like below, to get the data in the success funtion of jquery

**Jquery**

```
$ANALYZE = $('#submitID');

    $ANALYZE.click(function () {
        var objectID = document.getElementById('objectIDInput').value;

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("AnalyzeData")',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { 'objectID': objectID },
            success: function (data) {
               //data here refers the viewmodel
              // some logic
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
```

**Controller Method Code:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AnalyzeData (int objectID)
{
    List<string> retList = new List<string>();
    AnalyzeViewModel avm = new AnalyzeViewModel();

    try {
        retList = SOME LIST

        avm.fileData = retList.ToArray();

        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
        var obj = new
        {
            success = true,
            responseText = "Zones data has been calculated."
        };


        return Json(avm, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Hope it was helpful

Thanks

Karthik